# Create new table from multiple tables in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a setuation where i want to create a table from multiple table. In the new table i wrote the DAX below
table 1 is Assets and table two is Costs

```
NewTable =
CALCULATETABLE (
SUMMARIZE(Assets,
          Assets[AssetsSKEY],
        'Costs'[Type Name],
        "Forecast", SUM ( 'Costs'[Forecast Costs]),    
    ),Assets[AssetsKEY] <> BLANK()
)
```

it is giving error

[image]

What can I do guys,
Thanks

Comment: Isn't the expression supposed to be like this?

NewTable =
CALCULATETABLE (
SUMMARIZE(
FILTER( Assets,Assets[AssetsKEY] <> BLANK() ),
          Assets[AssetsSKEY],
        'Costs'[Type Name],
        "Forecast", SUM ( 'Costs'[Forecast Costs]),    
    )
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `,` just after your `SUM(...)`.

You can simplify your expression by using `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS`:

```
NewTable =
  SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
    Assets[AssetsSKEY],
    'Costs'[Type Name],
    "Forecast", SUM('Costs'[Forecast Costs])
  )
```